# Error: invalid signature: 0x4acf92ad (at position: 0x29)

Tags: javascript, excel, node.js, npm

I was trying to convert excel into json in node. I found a few modules that may be helpful.

I tried npm excel https://npmjs.org/package/excel‎

My app.js

```
var express = require('express');  //Call Express module
var app = express();  //Create server
var parseXlsx = require('excel');

        parseXlsx('Sheet.xlsx', function(err, data) {
            console.log('sdf');
            if(err) throw err;
            // data is an array of arrays
            console.log(data);
        });

app.listen(3003);
```

But I'm getting error

```
/home/local/user/Desktop/sample/node_modules/excel/node_modules/node-promise/promise.js:199

          throw error;
                ^
Error: invalid signature: 0x4acf92ad (at position: 0x29)
    at /home/local/user/Desktop/sample/node_modules/excel/node_modules/unzip/lib/parse.js:56:13
    at /home/local/user/Desktop/sample/node_modules/excel/node_modules/unzip/node_modules/pullstream/pullstream.js:101:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The question is probably too localized for StackOverflow. You might want to seek support directly with the express.js author. It may be related to this open issue on excel.js: https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js/issues/14

Comment: I have gone through this. But that didn't help me. That's why I published a question here.

Comment: Have you tried using other modules (such as https://www.npmjs.org/package/convert-json ) ?

Comment: Hi @Okky, Have you resolved this issue ? Now I am stuck with this same issue. Please share if you have any inputs on the same.